# Varios Detalles con FullCalendar Horas del Dia, Configuracion Español

Tags: fullcalendar

Amigos de StackOverflow, estoy implementando Fullcalendar en mi proyecto para la Universidad, pero tengo varias Dudas.

la Primera como hago para pasar los Botones, Dias de la Semana y Meses en Español.

La Segunda, cuando deseo configurar un evento me gustaria que apareciera el botón como el Datepicker para que se abra el calendario y poder seleccionar la fecha y la hora a asignar.

La Tercera, Cuando se abre el fullcalendar que aparezca en el dia actual, porque en la configuracion viene una fecha predeterminada y al abrir en la semana siguiente o mes siguiente, siempre aparece en dicha fecha a menos que manualmente se cambie en el codigo.

Cuarta, quisiera en la parte de editar el evento poder cambiar las horas tambien, porque con la opcion de arrastrar y soltar puedo cambiar el dia pero no la fecha.

Saludos, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Para cambiar el idioma de Fullcalendar debes de llamar un archivo js de la librería, en este caso se encontraría en fullcalendar/locale/es.js.

2.- Cuando yo quiero añadir un evento lo que hago es llamar un modal para ingresarle los datos(no se si te sirve, particularmente en tu caso), de esta forma

```
 dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, start, end, allDay) {


    $('#modal_registrar').modal();


},
```

4.- Al hacer click en un evento, llamo a otro modal para editar sus datos